# Why won't my child speak?

Tags: primary-schooler, communication

My son is 6 and he is absolutely can talk lots and knows lots of words in English and Japanese. My wife is a controlling person who doesn't believe in structure- has to do some now that son was going to elementary school (Summer break now) but nothing is on paper- I tried but she refuses to reference the timetable that I set up.  My son can't ask for a tissue- even say tissue rather he cries and points. He also can't say what he likes or dislikes or tell us about his day. Open questions get no response. Asking him directly why he is not speaking gets no response. Why won't he speak?

Comment: I think this is beyond the point where we can helpfully advise. You should consult a paediatrician or child psychiatrist. Your description of your problems with your wife suggests a lot of tension in your relationship, which may have something to do with your son's problems. Possibly family counselling would be a good thing.